# Freeform: submit results in system error message without a message

Tags: error, solspace-freeform, system-messages

weird problem. I have a website with freeform that suddenly broke. When you submit a form a basic ExpressionEngine error message is shown but without an error message.

[image: ExpressionEngine error message]

After discovering the problem i upgraded the system from ee2.3.1/freeform3.1.5 to ee2.6.0/freeform4.0.12 but the exact same problem keeps happening. I've already stipped down a test form to the bare minimal but that doesn't change anything.

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="adwords"
    return="homepage/verzonden"
}
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <button type="submit">Verzenden</button>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Anybody got a clue where to look next?

Answer (score 1):

The great people of solspace took a look at my systems and found the error.

It was caused by me using the Low NoSpam add-on. It was causing an error without outputting an error message. Disabling the add-on restored functionality.

Answer (score 0):

So the big question is, What changed before it broke?" ,htaccess? new server?
Are you getting any php errors?
Any console errors?
This is not an error I have seen before.
Any chance I can get a CP login and ftp access to your site?
support att solspace dott com

Comment: As far as i know nothing changed over the last few weeks. I've already tried sending an email via the messaging tools and that went out and arrived without any problems.

Will try one final thing on my own and then contact you via de given support adress.

Comment: Ok, just had contact with the hosting provider and they have no record of any changes to their hosting environment. I'll create a login for you and send it via email in the next few minutes.